# Is is possible to point a subdomain to a port address?

Tags: networking, iis-6, port-forwarding

Is it possible to point a subdomain to a port address?
For example sub.localhost -> localhost:82
How would I go about doing that in IIS 6?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to do this directly. You need to setup another web server at port 80 and set reverse proxy to localhost:82.

Answer (score 1):

The DNS system has nothing to do with ports, so you wouldn't be able to do it there.

If no port is given, a browser will always connect to port `80` for HTTP connections. Any other port used needs to be explicitly specified in the URL, you can't transparently use another port.

If you want to be able to type `http://localhost` into your browser and have a server at `localhost:82` kick into action, you will have to run some server at `localhost:80`. This server could either redirect or reverse proxy to port `82`.

Answer (score 0):

[PortMapper](http://www.analogx.com/contents/download/Network/pmapper/Freeware.htm) by AnalogX might help you do what you want.